# Get current paginator limit in cakePHP 3 view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.3

I use cakePHP 3.3 and I want to have a filter with the option to change the limit. This option should have the current limit selected.

What is the best way to get the current `limit` or results per page used in the Paginator in my view?

I use `<?= $this->Paginator->counter('{{current}}'); ?>` but this feels hacky and it is the limit as a string.
Also if the results are less than the limit, this will not show the limit but the number of found results.

Comment: You can create a variable with the number of pages to show, manually initialize the `paginator` as shown in the docs: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html and pass the variable to the view. I can't see an option to get the number of pages directly from the paginator in the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paginator component adds pagination details to the request objects params, using the key `paging`, where the data is nested using the alias of the table object.

Check

```
debug($this->request->param('paging'));
```

This data is easily accessible in your view templates via the paginator helpers `param()` method.

```
$this->Paginator->param('perPage');
```

So, why `perPage`? you may ask. Well, while there is also a `limit` parameter, this will always be `null` unless you haven't explicitly set a `limit` value in the pagination options, and a `limit` value is being passed in the URL (at least unless the passed value doesn't match the default). I don't really get the point of this behavior, but well, that's how it is.

Anyways, currently these are the supported parameters:

- `count`
- `current`
- `direction`
- `directionDefault`
- `finder`
- `limit`
- `nextPage`
- `page`
- `pageCount`
- `perPage`
- `prevPage`
- `scope`
- `sort`
- `sortDefault`

See also

- **[API > \Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper::param()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.Helper.PaginatorHelper.html#_param)**